# PostgreSQL Invalid Byte Sequence: How to find the record(s)

Tags: postgresql

For a certain table, this query runs fine:

```
SELECT "ID", "Abstract" FROM "Schema"."TableName"
WHERE "Abstract" LIKE '%Telefon%' OR "Abstract" LIKE '%telefon%';
```

Adding the function UPPER()

```
SELECT "ID", "Abstract" FROM "Schema"."TableName"
WHERE UPPER("Abstract") LIKE '%TELEFON%' ;
```

it runs into an error:
Invalid Byte-Sequence for Code »UTF8«: 0xc3 0x61

Please help me to identify the record(s) causing this.

Comment: Which PostgreSQL version? Is that a regular table or something like a view or a foreign table? Did you use `pg_upgrade` to upgrade from a very old version?

Comment: A regular table in PostgreSQL16.1

Comment: You have to go through the table row by row and fetch `"Abstract"` for each one in a loop, perhaps in a PL/pgSQL `DO` block.

Comment: And how do I find the affected row(s)?

Comment: https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/fix-bad-encoding-postgresql/ seems relevant

Comment: I've found it, thank you!
SELECT "ID", Upper("Abstract") FROM "Schema"."TableName" ORDER BY "ID" LIMIT 1000
Step by step ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can try is a `DO` statement like

```
DO $$
DECLARE
   i bigint;
   max_id bigint;
BEGIN
   SELECT max("ID") INTO max_id FROM "Schema"."TableName";
   FOR i IN 1..max_id LOOP
      BEGIN
         PERFORM upper("Abstract")
         FROM "Schema"."TableName"
         WHERE "ID" = i;
      EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
         RAISE NOTICE '"ID" = %', i;
      END;
   END LOOP;
END;$$;
```

The idea is to loop through all rows, trigger the error and report the primary key of the bad row.